# Write a proof to show that $M$ can be colored in with at most $\alpha +1$ colors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $M$ such that the max degree of any vertex is $\alpha$. Write a proof to show that $M$ can be colored in with at most $\alpha +1$ colors.

### My attempt

I am thinking that I should prove this with induction but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm will show you that you can color your graph with $k+1$ colors.

Just be greedy. Number the vertices in the graph from $1$ to $v$, where $v$ is the number of vertices in the graph.

Color $1$ with some color. Look at $2$. If it is connected to $1$, then it requires a different color, otherwise you can assign the same color to it.Look at $3$, and similarly until the end of the graph.

I claim this does your job. Why? Suppose the max degree of a vertex is $d$. Then the degree of every other vertex is less than or equal to $d$. Remember, in the greedy algorithm, you have a new color introduced if and only if the current vertex you are at **intersects all the previous vertices**, because then it cannot share the colors of any of these. Now, a vertex of degree at most $d$ intersects at most $d$ points at once, which means that after the $d$th vertex, no more colors need to be introduced since beyond that vertex, all vertices do not intersect **some** previous vertex, and then we assign that color to the vertex, ensuring we don't add a new color. Hence the most number of colors we use is $d+1$, the $1$ comes because the first vertex needs to have some color.